# Anchor tag no longer works

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Optional code to hide all divs
    $("#two").hide();
    $("#three").hide();
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#one').hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#two').hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#three').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue is `e.preventDefault()`, which stops the link behaviour. You need to either remove that line, or make the selector more specific to the elements you want.

Comment: Why are you using IDs with `.siblings()`?  IDs must be unique to the page, so there's no need to specify any parent elements and then search them.  Just `$("#one").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are doing something which you don't know.

The culprit is `e.preventDefault();`. It prevents the default action (of a redirect).
Remove that line, and everthing wil be fine.

Or else, be more specific in your selectors to make use of anchors only which you need and not all of them.

### [**READ MORE ABOUT `e.preventDefault`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to only target the required anchor element. your code is targeting all the anchors on page.

```
$("selector_target_anchor").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#one').hide();
 $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#two').hide();
 $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('#three').hide();
});
```